# Selenium IDE waitForElementPresent :visible not working with display:none to display:block

Tags: css-selectors, selenium-ide

I'm testing an application that unhides a div block when clicking on another span. (It's a mimic of a dropdown.)  That is, when I click on the correct element to display the div block, the `<div class="select-popup" style="display:none; z-index:auto;">` becomes `<div class="select-popup" style="display:block; z-index:1019;">` (other class and style attributes that don't change are left out) The only other attribute that changes in the style is z-index from

In Se IDE, I have

```
<tr>
   <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
   <td>css=.select-popup:visible</td>
   <td></td>
</tr>
```

However, it fails. I click the "Find" button and it doesn't see the displayed div block.
I'm using Firebug as my way to inspect the code and it has a nice console feature. I enter `$('.select-popup:visible');` It correctly finds the element when display:block is set and correctly does not find it when display:none is set.

Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong or is Se IDE broken in this way?

Comment: It seems :visible is just not working at all for me on Selenium IDE 2.6.0.
I test the css selector in Firebug and it works fine $('.popup:visible'), but when I set it in the IDE as css=.popup:visible, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, here's the answer.  :visible is a JQuery extension and is not part of the CSS spec.  What Firebug is doing is using JQuery to find it, whereas Selenium IDE does not utilize JQuery in its CSS Selectors.

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Here's an example.

Click on the "Help" link at the top of this page.  In firebug's Console, type:

```
$('.help-dialog:visible')
```

and click Run.  Note that it returns a value -> jQuery(div.topbar-dialog.help-dialog.js-help-dialog.dno)

Now, in Selenium IDE 2.6.0, enter

```
css=.help-dialog:visible
```

in the Target box and click the Find button. It does not find the element.

---

The correct answer is to search on the element's style attribute, display property. The following line will find an element that is visible (and not hidden).

```
css=.help-dialog:not([style*="display: none"])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Machtyn! It really saved my time. Can you please let me know what is the best place to get all the possible complex css selectors for Selenium? I did not find all possible css selectors example on selenium doc website: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-by-css

Comment: W3schools.com is an excellent resource. Google also has good resource pages for him and can. :visible and :contains are JQuery. But :first :last :nth-child and a few others are css3.

Answer (score -2):

I don't get your question but guessing you are fighting to access some nested element of same class
but hope below link is your complete solution please view it

[Selenium how to access two controls of same css class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657401/selenium-how-to-access-two-controls-of-same-css-class)