# Selenium how to access two controls of same css class

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-ide, load-testing

I am doing testing using selenium ide.
My objective is to verify the following

1) Max and Min length property of text boxes.
2) Verify the texts of the labels

My html code is as below:

```
<div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="input01">Email</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input name="data[Salon][username]" class="span4" id="username" placeholder="Username or Email" type="text"/>                                   
                                    </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="input01">Password</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input name="data[Salon][password]" class="span4" id="password" placeholder="Required" type="password"/>                                                                    
</div>
```

But in the above I am facing following problems:

a) I have problem in accessing the labels for assertText or assertElementPresent since they are having same class name.

b) I don't know how verify the Max and Min length property of the Text boxes.

And please note that when I am trying to use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("control-label")

I am getting the following error:

[error] locator not found: document.getElementsByClassName("control-lable"), error = TypeError: e.scrollIntoView is not a function
```

Comment: Why is the load-tesing tag on your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access first label via:

```
css=div[class='control-group'] label[class='control-label']:contains('Email')
```

You can access second lavel via:

```
css=div[class='control-group'] label[class='control-label']:contains('Password')
```

Use these with command assertElementPresent, "contains" in element locator allows you to verify text in it.

Also you can use xpath:

```
//div[@class='control-group']//label[@class='control-label'][text()='Email']
//div[@class='control-group']//label[@class='control-label'][text()='Password']
```

Usually maxlength property is set as attribute of the input, but i can't see it in your html code.. But you can try:

storeAttribute (Selenium IDE's command) and as target you can use xpath:

```
/div[@class='control-group']//label[@class='control-label'][text()='Email']/@maxlength
```

save it to some var (eg set to the value field smthg like attLength) and then echo this var like: Selenium IDE's command echo and as put to the target field ${attLength}

Comment: Sorry sir but it is not working it is giving following error  [error] locator not found: css=div[class='control-group'] label[class='control-label']:contains('Password')

Comment: Sir but the shorter version of it as css=label[class='control-label']:contains('Password') is working thank you sir

Comment: :contains is JQuery and not valid CSS3. Just be aware that you may run into problems using SeIDE.