# Is there any best way to identify Uniqueness of web pages in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In my case, I've webelements of type anchor tags., << hyper links>> ., when i click on them, they are broken some times, not navigating to target webpage..

I'm using Title of the newly loaded page ., ( after clicking of the link ) to verify whether it is loaded or not. but , in some scenarios, morthan one link have same title ., in such cases,

im going with URL of the newly loaded page.. is it suffice ?

Is there any other best way to handle this situation

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: "uniqueness of web pages"?

Comment: @audi If you are asking whether the URL of the page should be enough to identify a page uniquely... Well, it depends on what "uniqueness" means in light of **your specific goals**. For instance, a page at a given URL may contain data that is periodically refreshed. If a refresh makes it a different page *as far as you are concerned* then you can't rely on the URL. It's not clear what your goals are.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have two different ways possible firstly

1) You can inspect your html and can navigate using the following compact answer

[Selenium how to access two controls of same css class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657401/selenium-how-to-access-two-controls-of-same-css-class)

2) No, if you using URL for the testing it is not recommended, please try to follow the
page objects model for testing.
which is mentioned below

http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are other ways to check the uniqueness of two web pages and code for that will be like this:

```
   WebElement oldPageElement = driver.findElement(By.tagName("html"));   
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("linkXpath")).click();
   WebElement newPageElement = driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")); 
   Assert.assertTrue(newPageElement != oldPageElement , "Clicked Link is Ok & it opens a new page");
```

So basically above code compares two objects of `WebElement` after clicking on a link. If both object do not match to each other it means click on link opened a new page.

Comment: Thank you for all your responses

Comment: Thank you for all your responses
Uniqueness meaning : URL & Title are same in my case, but page source is different, say today i've 3 web elements of <<text box >> type . but later fourth web element is added . Now, i should say "you are trying to execute test on new page" whenever i try to execute my script @Louis